# how to remove in url two get id

Tags: php, .htaccess

now my url is

```
detail.php?category=abc&model=126
```

and i want like this

```
detail/abc-126.html
```

and i am using this code in 
but it is not working properly

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^detail/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ detail.php?category=$2&model=$2
```

and my 2nd question is
suppose if i use a dir like this in my website
foldername

```
www.example.com/foldername/detail/abc-126.html
```

and my php file in this folder

```
www.example.com/foldername/detail.php
```

and my .htaccess file in

```
www.example.com/.htaccess
```

is here

so how can i use with foldername

and this is not a duplicate post i search many sites but i did not understand how to solve this

so please help me to fix this issue
thanks

Comment: Well, you have two conditions and you are referencing `$2` twice instead of `$1` & `$2`. So that is one problem. That probably won't solve your issue because I am not very good at rewrites, but it's a start.

Comment: Also you are wanting `abc-126.html` but you have a forward slash in-between your rewrite like so `)/(`.

Comment: well thanks bro its a small thing and i spend 1 hour but what the problem i did not find but you solve my problem thanks

Comment: and i have one more question can you help me

Comment: I posted it as an answer, that way other developers won't keep hitting back to it when it's solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63258/discussion-between-rasclatt-and-user3000993).

Comment: i update my question please check

Comment: I am not sure if my updated answer addresses your 2nd question, so you may have to expound on your question. It's a little unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two conditions and you are referencing `$2` twice instead of `$1` & `$2`. So that is one problem. That probably won't solve your issue because I am not very good at rewrites, but it's a start.

Also you are wanting `abc-126.html` but you have a forward slash in between your rewrite like so `)/(`.

For your second question, I am not 100% sure what you are asking, but if the `.htaccess` file is in the parent directory, it's effect is felt through the children directories unless you put a new `.htaccess` file in the child directory.

Comment: No problem! For not knowing much about rewrites, I did alright! :D

Answer (score 1):

You are capturing two things, `$1` and `$2`. When you create the path that it should be redirected to you only use `$2`. You have to use both of them in order for this to work:

```
                                          .-------------------------------------.
                            .------------/------------------------------.        \
                    |----- $1 -----| |- $2 -|                            \        \
RewriteRule ^detail/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ detail.php?category=$1&model=$2
```